# Mutually exclusive group by in Linq

Tags: c#, linq, grouping

I want to catch duplicates mutually exclusively, that is, I need to show that both the first and the third items are duplicates, and that the first and the fourth items are duplicates.

```
public class Foo
{
    public String Name { get; set; }
    public String SName { get; set; }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var list = new List<Foo>();
        list.Add(new Foo { Name = "a", SName = "d" });
        list.Add(new Foo { Name = "b", SName = "e" });
        list.Add(new Foo { Name = "c", SName = "a" });
        list.Add(new Foo { Name = "a", SName = "f" });

        // only groups by 1 name
        var duplicates = list.GroupBy(i => i.Name).Where(g => g.Count() > 1).Select(g => g.Key);
    }
}
```

I know this can be done trivially with foreach, I want to learn.

Comment: Do you mean you want to consider `Name` and `SName` as equivalent in terms of comparison?

Comment: In third line did you mean SName = "SName1" ?

Comment: @AndriyBuday, no.  The point is that Name and SName can't be the same, and I need to find that.

Comment: I changed the string values, I hope that helps.  Context:  While they're stored as different columns, the user can pick which one they want to display on a segment in our UI, and SName is nullable, so we need to require that for any given Foo, both it's Name and SName must be unique to all other Name and SName values.

Comment: PS:  I know this is trivial with a couple foreach loops.  I want to use it as an opportunity to learn more about Linq.

Comment: So as result you want to get "a" and "c" ?

Comment: @JoeBehymer can you please explain why first and third items considered to be duplicates?

Comment: @Joe, I think you should move your last comment into your question, as it's quite important, and maybe also move the last comment block out of your code (it will be more readable in the question itself IMHO).

Comment: Ideally, I'd get 3 Foo's, all but the second one.

Comment: The first and third item are duplicates because they both have "a" for one of their names.

Imagine a list, each time you add to the list you must verify that the new items Name and SName values are completely unique to all other Name and SName values in the list.  Make sense?

Comment: Do you have a large list, which is to say, is performance a significant concern?

Comment: "Large" is so scientific, isn't it? :)  

Honestly, if you submit the only working Linq solution, you'll get "answer".  If someone comes by with a significantly faster solution, I'll probably switch it.  That said, if the Linq solution is slower than the foreach solution, I won't use it anyway :)

Comment: Every comment reveals a new aspect that invalidates all existing answers. This makes it very inconvenient to help...

Comment: I think the question text describes the question correctly, does it not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So we'll start out by getting all of the repeated name values from either column, this is fairly easy:

```
IEnumerable<string> repeatedNames = list.SelectMany(foo => new[] { foo.Name, foo.SName })
    .GroupBy(name => name)
    .Where (g => g.Count () > 1)
    .Select(g => g.Key);
```

Next we take each of those names and find all of the items that contain that value.  The end result is a sequence for each distinct name where the sequence is all of the `Foo` items containing that value.

```
IEnumerable<List<Foo>> groupings = repeatedNames .Select(name =>
    list.Where(foo => foo.Name == name || foo.SName == name).ToList());
```

If you want it to be, instead of a sequence of Lists of Foos, a sequence of an item with both the distinct value and a sequence then it's easy enough to add in:

```
var groupings = repeatedNames .Select(name => new
    {
        Name = name,
        Foos = list.Where(foo => foo.Name == name || foo.SName == name).ToList()
    });
```

Comment: This is perfect, thank you.  Note that you can use the following as a shortcut for your last item (I think, at least it works for my scenario):  groupings.SelectMany(i=>i)

Comment: @JoeBehymer In this particular case "a" is the only name duplicated, so there is only one list.  If there were 3 Foos with an "a" and two with a "b" then the question is do you want all of the `Foo` items with either an "a" or a "b" or do you want a list of the "a"s and a list of the "b"s.  I coded the latter.

Comment: Oh I see.  For my scenario the latter is fine.  Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want the values that are duplicated, rather than the indexes at which they occur, then you can use `SelectMany` to convert the names into a single list of strings before doing the grouping:

```
var duplicates2 = list.SelectMany(n => new string[] {n.Name, n.SName})
                      .GroupBy(g => g)
                      .Where (g => g.Count () > 1)
                      .Select(g => g.Key)
                      .ToList();
```

**Edit:**
If you want the `Foo` objects instead of just the strings, you can select them like this:

```
var duplicates3 = list.Where(n => duplicates2.Contains(n.Name) ||
                                  duplicates2.Contains(n.SName));
```

Comment: That gives all of the names that are duplicated, not all of the Foos for each name that is duplicated.  Half way there

Answer (score 0):

I came up with this:

```
// Will return "a" - one which you already had
var duplicatesBetweenNames = list.GroupBy(i => i.Name)
    .Where(g => g.Count() > 1)
    .Select(g => g.Key).ToArray();

var duplicatedInSName = list.Select(x => x.Name)
    .Intersect(list.Select(x => x.SName));
// Will return "c" - represents Names where in SName is duplicate
var duplicatesBetweenNameAndSName = list
    .Where(f => duplicatedInSName.Contains(f.SName))
    .Select(x=>x.Name).ToArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

Interesting thread, I just thought that the query syntax is very expressive in this case:

```
var r = from l in list
        from s in new [] {l.Name,l.SName}
        group s by s into g
        where g.Count() > 1
        select g.Key into u
        from l in list
        where u.Contains(l.Name) || u.Contains(l.SName)
        select l;
```